# How Can I Hover over on an invisible button using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

There is an invisible button on my webpage which becomes visible when a mouse hover is done on the element. What I Have to do is

Hover over the element

when I run selenium scripts it fails when reaches to invisible element.How can I find that invisible button and how to hover

Comment: If button is invisible how user can identify/hover over it? Do you mean disabled?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.FindElement(By.Id(""));
actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.Build().Perform();
```

you can find your button by id/xpath/className and so on ...

Comment: it is not working. shows org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'Options')]"}

Comment: Check if the element is in the same frame that you using

Comment: and one more thing i think you need to make that element visible so you need to hover the parent element of that a tag and after that click on it